# DATAFRAME: drop duplicates where column's values are equal for unique key

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to drop duplicates from DF where column's values are equal for one unique key.
Example:

In:

```
KEY         SYSTEM
TD-438426   AAA
TD-438426   BBB
TD-438426   AAA
TD-438709   BBB
TD-438709   BBB
TD-438750   CCC
TD-438750   CCC
TD-438750   CCC
TD-438874   AAA
TD-438874   BBB
```

Out:

```
KEY         SYSTEM
TD-438426   AAA
TD-438426   BBB
TD-438709   BBB
TD-438750   CCC
TD-438874   AAA
TD-438874   BBB
```

P.S. Of course there are some exceptions that I want to catch.

In:

```
KEY         TEST    SYSTEM
TD-438426   ABC     AAA
TD-438426   ABC     BBB
```

Out:

```
KEY         TEST    SYSTEM
TD-438426   ABC     AAA
TD-438426   ABC     BBB
```

And

In:

```
KEY         TEST    SYSTEM
TD-438426   ABC     AAA
TD-438426   CBA     AAA
```

Out:

```
KEY         TEST    SYSTEM
TD-438426   ABC     AAA
```

Comment: IIUC you can use `df.drop_duplicates()`

Comment: I know, but there will be only unique keys in the amount of 1, this is not I want, there is a condition in the task

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates()` does what you are asking for in your output. Please clarify what is missing for us to help you better. I have left an answer below describing the two arguments which might be useful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @mcsioni mentioned in the comments, what you are looking for is `df.drop_duplicates()`

Also, it is useful to understand two arguments of this method, namely, `subset` and `keep`.

E.g., You want to retain only unique values in the `KEY` column and keep the first `SYSTEM` value for each unique `KEY`, you'd do:

`df.drop_duplicates(subset=['KEY'], keep='first')`

If you just used `df.drop_duplicates()` without any arguments, the subset will be all the columns, which is what your desired output is asking for.

**EDIT**

To keep up with your new requirement, do this:

`df.drop_duplicates(subset=['KEY', 'SYSTEM'], keep='first')`

Note: The default behavior for the `keep` argument is `'first'` but doesn't hurt to be explicit when working with high-level libraries like pandas.

Comment: I don't need keep the first ```SYSTEM``` value, check "In" and "Out". For ```TD-438426``` there are 3 rows containing "AAA", "BBB", "AAA". I need leave unique rows based on values. So it will be "AAA" and "BBB" for ```TD-438426```

Comment: Then that would just be `df.drop_duplicates()` as mentioned.

Comment: yes, it works but I have another problem, of course there are some other columns, there are some exceptions, I edited the post, can you check it please?

Comment: the two cases are your desired outcomes right? I anticipated that there'd be more columns so this is where the `subset` argument comes in handy - set your subset to be the `KEY` and `SYSTEM` columns. And perhaps specify a policy for how to handle the `TEST` column, which from your example  seems to be to keep the first: `keep='first'` (which is the default policy but doesn't hurt to be explicit here)